# Bot Builder v3 SDK to v4 SDK Migration Guidance

Tags: botframework, bots

I'm searching for guidance on Bot Builder v3 SDK to v4 SDK migration.
Any conversion guide you can advise?
According to the [product github](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/wiki/Roadmap) a migration from V3 to V4 (documentation and samples) guide may be available by Feb.
Shall I  wait for that?
Has anyone hear about any tool that will be doing the migration automatically?

Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a migration path planned where you'll be able to recompile with some level of source compatibility and that will then run on top of the V4 runtime... a bridge if you will. Ultimately to take full advantage of V4 features you need to really start fresh. I'm not aware of any tooling in the works that would help migrate from V3 style dialog code to V4, only the binary bridge and documentation.

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot for the guidance Drew.